# Git merge fails to add new lines

Tags: git, csv, magento-1.9

I am using Mageploy to version control Admin Panel changes between developers, but it appears Git is unable to merge even **completely different** lines in the CSV file that contains the records of what actions have been performed.

In every case, when two developers change something in the Admin Panel on their local environment and commit the change, if they didn't do it in turns (one of them commits, the other one merges, then commits, then the first one merges), git will want them to **pick** between the one or the other branch upon merge.

In the image below you can see the CSV of branch **test1** and the CSV of branch **test2**. The lines are completely different, but even none of the available merge strategies work (octopus ours recursive resolve subtree).

[image: Mageploy CSV in Notepad++ compare mode]

I simply need the line from test2 to be **added** to all the lines in test1. And, ideally, merge properly without conflict whether it was test2 added to test1 or test1 added to test2 (since adding lines normally puts them at the bottom).

Example:

test1.csv

```
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test1-a
test1-b
```

test2.csv

```
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test2-c
```

Developer **one** merges test2 into their test1

```
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test1-a
test1-b
test2-c
```

Developer **two** merges test 1 into their test2

```
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test2-c
test1-a
test1-b
```

Comment: Is your issue that data is being discarded during the merge, or that you are/are not getting a merge conflict?

Comment: I am always getting a merge conflict that asks me to pick either the lines added in test1 or the lines added in test2, not both.

Comment: If Git can't automatically resolve the merge, then it can't automatically resolve the merge.  Actually, the worse problem would be automatic resolution which also discards something you want to retain.  But this doesn't appear to be your problem.

Comment: Yes, the lines are clearly completely different, so both should be kept. Maybe it's something about Git handling CSV files in particular?

Comment: No, this makes perfect sense from the point of view of what Git is assuming here.  In the case of merge `test2` into `test1`, the `test2-c` line rightfully _should_ appear last, because the merge happened _after_ `test1.csv` was authored, at least from the point of view of its author.  And vice-versa for the other scenario.  I guess order of lines isn't such a big deal when dealing with computer code as opposed to human readable texts.

Comment: The problem is that it is __not__ adding the line at all, it is asking to choose either test2 or test1. Not combining them.

Comment: How are you resolving the merge conflict?  It sounds to me that all the data is there.  I recommend resolving from your IDE, not a fancy tool.

Comment: Just the commandline. While on branch test1 `git merge test2` gives me "Auto-merging var/mageploy/mageploy_all.csv

CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in var/mageploy/mageploy_all.csv

Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result"

Comment: I don't think that it is throwing away information.  Just resolve the conflicts and move on to your next task.

Comment: [Vimdiff conflict](https://puu.sh/s65xb/f1c68a618b.png), I would not have this problem if I didn't have this problem.

Comment: This is a completely normal merge conflict.

Comment: I want all those lines to be automatically added into the file instead of every time manually deleting the merge marks.

Comment: You may not be able to do this, sorry.

Comment: Surely there has to be a way for something as simple as simply adding lines?

Comment: You can do something like tell Git to keep one parent branch's version, but this wouldn't give you what you want.  In general, you may encounter merge conflicts when using Git or any other VCS tool.  It is completely normal, and you should try to get proficient at resolving them as you will encounter them throughout your career.

Comment: Sorry if I made this too unclear but this is not a matter of resolving merge conflicts, which I have no problems with.

This scenario happens 100% of the time when instead the newly added lines should simply be appended during the merge. It seems like the simplest merge technique possible, yet Git itself has no way to handle it.

This removes the possibility to automate the merging of these changes, unless using a script that removes all three lines of merge marks that are always added and completes the merge for the user.

Comment: AFAIK the presence of merge conflicts means Git could not resolve it on its own.  There is no magic pill to prevent this always.

Comment: Git doesn't *ask* you to do anything, it just dumps the whole merge conflict in your lap (or in your file, which amounts to the same thing) and *forces* you to clean up the mess. :-) But note that you can `git checkout -m` the conflicted file, and when you do that, you can specify `--ours` or `--theirs` to choose one or the other. What's missing is the equivalents of `-X ours`, `-X theirs`, and `-X union`, all of which Mercurial provides "out of the box". These are all in `git merge-file` but for some reason there is no porcelain to make `git merge-file` more usable.

Comment: All that said, Git *does* support custom merge drivers, and you could write one that detects your particular situation and applies your merge algorithm. See the `gitattributes` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to make Git keep all lines in the CSV file during the merge without a conflict. According to comments by @tim-biegelesein and @torek, there is no way to make Git take the lines from both branches.

I will be using something like this to work around that in my development automation script. It simply removes the merge marks and commits the merge.

```
git merge $targetBranch
sed -i -e "/<<<<<<<\|=======\|>>>>>>>/d" /path/to/mageploy_all.csv
git commit --all --file .git/MERGE_MSG
```

The argument `--no-edit` did not work to use the default merge message without opening the editor. Specifying the merge message file works instead.

---

This, however, still seems susceptible to an issue shown in the Example in my question above - the order of these merges.

I suspect that Git will make another conflict when it sees a different order of the lines in the CSV as test1 was merged with test2 while test2 was merged with test1, seeing the lines have swapped places.
Does not make sense to conflict on that, or at least to not have any merge strategy for that, but seems the only option now is to write more code to work around these cases.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @torek's comment using [git merge-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file): Suppose we have our merge conflict (I recreated the setup just like the OP's, see below), first restore the previous versions of our file `test1.csv` as temporary files...

```bash
% git show :1:test1.csv > common
% git show :2:test1.csv > ours
% git show :3:test1.csv > theirs
```

...then do the merge "by hand" (`-p` is for stdout): Add the merged file as `test1.csv`, clean the temporary files and commit the merge:

```bash
% git merge-file -p ours common theirs --union > test1.csv
% git add test1.csv
% git clean  # remove ours, common, theirs
```

This could be easily scripted. For comparison, here is the output for the other "merge"-options, `--ours` and `--theirs`, respectively:

```bash
% git merge-file -p ours common theirs --ours  
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test1-a
test1-b

% git merge-file -p ours common theirs --theirs                                                                 
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test2-c

% git merge-file -p ours common theirs --union
old-entry
old-entry
old-entry
test1-a
test1-b
test2-c
```

The `--union` is exactly what the OP wants!

I find this kind of merge conflict *ubiquitous*, especially when merging auto-generated files. I agree with @Tim Biegeleisen that git should not merge this *automagically*, but why it does not have some sort of merge strategy *option* to resolve this is a really good question.

---

#### (the setup)

```bash
[test1] % git show test1                                                                                                                                           
...                                                                                                                                                                                                 
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 old-entry                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 old-entry                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 old-entry                                                                                                                                                                                                         
+test1-a                                                                                                                                                                                                           
+test1-b                                                                                                                                                                                                           

[test1] % git show test2                                                                                                                                           
...
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 old-entry
 old-entry
 old-entry
+test2-c

[test1] % git merge test2
Auto-merging test1.csv
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in test1.csv
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```